# Event target - targeting all divs, with a classname in the nextSibling?

Tags: javascript

New to javascript...

I'm trying to build an event handler, that will set the tabIndex  of a set of links to 0 when it's clicked... I'm unsure how to target that exactly.

Example:

```
<div id="a">Link</div>
<div id="b">
    <div class="link" tabIndex="-1">Link 1</div>
    <div class="link" tabIndex="-1">Link 2</div>
    <div class="link" tabIndex="-1">Link 3</div>
</div>
```

Im looking ion how to target all the divs with class "link" in #b when I click on #a.

Any advice appreciated!!

Comment: So what's the problem? Binding an event listening in the first place? Finding the elements you want to change? Setting the attribute once you've found the attribute? Loading the JS into the page in the first place? The code you've provided so far suggests you should be looking at an [introduction to JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) rather than asking SO to write your code for you.

Comment: I'm asking how to target the divs in #b, as Im a little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the already given answer I do recommend making use of a more meaningful markup and, if available/possible, taking advantage of a modern DOM.

```js
function nullifyTabIndex(elmNode) {
  elmNode.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
}
function handleNullifyTabIndices(evt) {
  var
    tabItemList = document.body.querySelectorAll('#b > li');

  tabItemList.forEach(nullifyTabIndex);
}
function registerHandlingOfTabindexChange(evt) {
  var
    elmTrigger = document.body.querySelector('#a');

  elmTrigger.addEventListener('click', handleNullifyTabIndices, false);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', registerHandlingOfTabindexChange, false);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="a">Trigger Tab Index Change</a>
<nav>
  <ul id="b">
    <li tabindex="-1"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li tabindex="-1"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li tabindex="-1"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should help you.

Html:

```
<div id="a">Link</div>
<div id="b">
    <div class="link" tabIndex="-1">Link 1</div>
    <div class="link" tabIndex="-1">Link 2</div>
    <div class="link" tabIndex="-1">Link 3</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () { test() }; //Call the test function below on load

function test() {
    document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click", updateAttribute); //attach event listener to div with id "a"
}

function updateAttribute()
{
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("link"); //Get all div elements with class name "link" under div "b"

    for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) //Loop through all div elements and set attribute "tabIndex" to "0"
        ele[i].setAttribute("tabIndex", "0");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Really appreciated.